# ERB view embedded in a Haml layout: what to do about whitespace now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, erb

I have a Rails 3 app where the views are all done in Haml. However, there are some views coming from a required gems that are in ERB, and Haml is adding whitespace, and it's messing up textareas and such. (If you're not familiar with this aspect of haml, [look here](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.FAQ.html#q-preserve).)

I'd rather not have to convert my layout to ERB, and because the gem is in ERB, all of the traditional Haml whitespace solutions don't help.

So how do I get my textareas (and <pre>s etc) not to wrap? Anything smart I can do in my app is good, otherwise I'd be happy to apply a patch to the original gem.

---

**Edit** I think I might have figured out a few decent answers.

One thing that works on the haml end is `Haml::Template.options[:ugly] = true`, which eliminates all whitespace. Meh, this might be the best solution, but where's my whitespace :( I liked it, when it wasn't messing up my app.

Another idea was to patch the gem to automatically convert \n characters to &#x000A; in a before_save, which mimics what Haml does in the link i linked to in my original question... but that might be a bit of a pain.

The final solution I came up with, which also seems to work, is to create a _form.html.haml document that sits right next to the _form.html.erb document in the plugin, and is identical. Apparently, the plugin doesn't need to depend on Haml, but if the parent app is rendering Haml, it'll look for a haml view before it looks for an ERB view. There's one caveat, though, and that's that Haml actually needs to be loaded at the beginning of the app. So I have a line at the bottom of application.rb now that just says 'Haml' all by itself.

So for anybody else having this problem, now you've got 3 solutions to pick from, and if you've got a better one, please post it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the :preserve filter?

See http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#preserve-filter

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for responding- I'm confused how this would apply. My layout is in Haml, but the rendered template (coming from a plugin) is ERB. So somewhere in my layout is a `= yield`, where the templates within my app are all in Haml, but the templates in the plugin are ERB. I can't place a `:preserve` filter above the yield, and I can't place it within the ERB template, but did you have something else in mind?

Comment: With that knowledge in hand, I'm not certain :preserve would do you any good. My other thought was to install the **maruku** gem and put your yield under a :markdown line, but I'm not sure that would work, either. I think it might be easier to visualize your problem with some example source code to see how the ERB / HAML is interacting.

Comment: Dave, an example would be any app that uses Haml for markup but makes use of the Devise gem. Devise adds templates, and those views are implemented in ERB, even if the application it gets embedded in has Haml templates/layouts. If Devise were to have a textarea in any of its forms, the same problem would crop up.